# Apache Tika server request to get 'main content' instead of 'plain text'

Tags: ruby, http, put, apache-tika

I am experimenting with Apache Tika: app & server, gui and command line.

With Tika app, I can do something like

```
    java -jar tika-app-1.7.jar --gui
```

and choose 'View' -> 'Main content', or

```
    java -jar tika-app-1.7.jar --text-main http://www.cnn.com/2015/07/09/politics/russian-bombers-u-s-intercept-july-4/index.html
```

I need main content, but it seems in a server mode I can only get plain text. I am checking [this guide](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS).

```
    curl -s "http://amzn.com/B005IWM8PU" | curl -X PUT -T - http://<server_ip>:9998/meta
    curl -s "http://amzn.com/B005IWM8PU" | curl -X PUT -T - http://<server_ip>:9998/tika
```

Maybe, something that comes after http://:9998/ will do the trick?
Is there any way do get main content in a server mode?

At the end, the request has to be made in Ruby, tika-server-1.3.jar. So far looks like this:

```
    require "net/http"

    tika_prefix = URI('http://<server_ip>:9998/tika')
    url = 'http://www.cnn.com/2015/07/09/politics/russian-bombers-u-s-intercept-july-4/index.html'
    request = Net::HTTP::Put.new(tika_prefix.to_s)
    request.body = url
    request.content_type = 'text/html'
    http = Net::HTTP.start(tika_prefix.hostname, tika_prefix.port)
    http.request(request).body
```

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, so I've sent an email to Tika mailing list. If someone replies, I'll let you know.

Comment: Did you maybe find a way to get `--text-main` in Tika-Server?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible as of today. Tika 1.15 now implements [TIKA-2343](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2343) feature request, which adds `--text-main` equivalent in server mode.

`vaites/php-apache-tika` is a PHP binding for Tika that I use, and I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/vaites/php-apache-tika/issues/5) regarding this, so we should be able to see it being implemented soon.

EDIT: The PHP Binding library now supports this feature.